# Page scrolls down when clicking on toggle menu

Tags: javascript

So I have a toggle menu on my site and when I click on it to open it the page scrolls on its own. I have no idea what to do. Could you please help me stop the automatic scroll? Thank you so much!!

If you don't see the automatic scroll, try adding some text so that the page can scroll and you'll see how it scrolls down.

```js
// TOGGLE MENU 

var theToggle = document.getElementById('toggle');
function hasClass(elem, className) {
    return new RegExp(' ' + className + ' ').test(' ' + elem.className + ' ');
}
function addClass(elem, className) {
    if (!hasClass(elem, className)) {
        elem.className += ' ' + className;
    }
}
function removeClass(elem, className) {
    var newClass = ' ' + elem.className.replace(/[\t\r\n]/g, ' ') + ' ';
    if (hasClass(elem, className)) {
        while (newClass.indexOf(' ' + className + ' ') >= 0) {
            if (window.CP.shouldStopExecution(1)) {
                break;
            }
            newClass = newClass.replace(' ' + className + ' ', ' ');
        }
        elem.className = newClass.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '');
        window.CP.exitedLoop(1);
    }
}
function toggleClass(elem, className) {
    var classes = elem.className.split(' ');
    var i = classes.indexOf(className);
    if(i == -1)
        classes.push(className);
    else
        classes.splice(i,1);
    elem.className = classes.join(' ');
}
theToggle.addEventListener("click", function(){
   toggleClass(this, 'on');
   return false;
});
```

```css
#toggle {
    display: block;
    width: 28px;
    height: 30px;
    position:fixed;
    top:35px;
    left:30px; 
}

#toggle span:after, #toggle span:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: -9px;
}

#toggle span:after {
    top: 9px;
}

#toggle span {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
}

#toggle span, #toggle span:after, #toggle span:before {
    width: 100%;
    height: 4px;
    background-color: #000;
    transition: all 0.3s;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    border-radius: 0px;
}

/* on activation */
#toggle.on span {
    background-color: transparent;
}

#toggle.on span:before {
    transform: rotate(45deg) translate(5px, 5px);
}

#toggle.on span:after {
    transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(7px, -8px);
}

#toggle.on + #menu {
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
    transition: opacity .4s;
}

/* menu appearance*/
#menu {
    position: absolute;
    color: #999;
    width: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
    background: white;
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    transition: opacity .4s;
    margin-top:75px;
    font-weight:700;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    color: #000;
}

#menu:after {
    position: absolute;
    top: -15px;
    left: 95px;
    content: "";
    display: block;
    border-left: 15px solid transparent;
    border-right: 15px solid transparent;
    transition: opacity .4s;
}

#menu ul, #menu li, #menu li a {
    list-style: none;
    display: block;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#menu li a {   
    padding: 15px;
    color: #888;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight:700;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    color: #000;
}

#menu li a:hover, #menu li a:focus {
    background: #000;
    color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="mobile">
            
                <a href="#menu" id="toggle"><span></span></a>

                <div id="menu">
                  <ul>
                    <li><a href="/">News</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/zara/">Biografia</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/zara/discografia/">Discografia</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/sito/">Zara Larsson Italia</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/contatti/">Contattaci</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
            
            </div>
```

Comment: I have a theory. [`visibility`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/visibility) doesn't show the element, but it still affects other elements. _"The box is invisible (fully transparent, nothing is drawn), but still affects layout."_ When `visibility` is updated (from `visible` to `hidden` and vice versa), the element (which is larger than the screen height) is 'redrawn' and so it pushes the scroll to the bottom of the page. Try using `display: none` and `display: block` so it doesn't affect the page layout

Comment: @MatheusAvellar it still scrolls :/

Comment: Well, yeah, but now it only scrolls when you _open_ the menu! Ta-da! Yeah, this isn't a solution, is more of a tip, hence why I only posted it as a comment. Sorry about that! I'll try to think of a nice solution to it

Comment: can u please reproduce the exact problem? cuz for 5 minutes I am trying and don't know where to introduce that text to see the scroll.

Comment: to be true, that is a weird way to do a toggle menu. but anyway ))

Comment: by the way, that is not from the js, because if you remove it, the scroll will still happen

Answer (score 0):

My solution, I assume that the scroll was due that you made the element visible/hidden and it will scroll to it (as @Matheus) said above in the comments. my solution is this.

instead of position absolute, make it fixed and give it top & bottom a 0 value this will scale it to the whole screen.

```
#menu {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;

    color: #999;
    width: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
    background: white;
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    transition: opacity .4s;
    font-weight:700;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    color: #000;
}
```

add z-index to hamburger so that it will stay on top.

```
#toggle {
    display: block;
    width: 28px;
    height: 30px;
    position:fixed;
    top:35px;
    left:30px; 
    z-index: 99999;
}
```

Comment: it still scrolls